# F# Performance Impact of Checked Calcs?

Tags: performance, f#, integer-overflow

Is there a performance impact from using the Checked module?  I've tested it out with sequences of type int and see no noticeable difference.  Sometimes the checked version is faster and sometimes unchecked is faster, but generally not by much.

```
Seq.initInfinite (fun x-> x) |> Seq.item 1000000000;;
```

> ```
> Real: 00:00:05.272, CPU: 00:00:05.272, GC gen0: 0, gen1: 0, gen2: 0
> val it : int = 1000000000
> ```

```
open Checked

Seq.initInfinite (fun x-> x) |> Seq.item 1000000000;;
```

> ```
> Real: 00:00:04.785, CPU: 00:00:04.773, GC gen0: 0, gen1: 0, gen2: 0
> val it : int = 1000000000
> ```

Basically I'm trying to figure out if there would be any downside to always opening Checked.  (I encountered an overflow that wasn't immediately obvious, so I'm now playing the role of the jilted lover who doesn't want another broken heart.)  The only non-contrived reason I can come up with for not always using Checked is if there were some performance hit, but I haven't seen one yet.

Comment: Note that you don't appear to be using any arithmetic operators in your example, so it's probably not a good test of their efficiency...

Comment: Maybe so, but the integer types are overloaded in FSharp.Core.Operators.Checked so part of the question is determining whether there is an impact to regular use of int types when overflow may not be a concern.

Comment: Those aren't types you're seeing, those are functions for converting to numeric types.  The types are exactly the same so your current test is not going to show anything.  If you do some arithmetic operations with checked, there will be some extra IL instructions so it will plausibly be a bit slower but rarely enough to worry about.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you measure performance it's usually not a good idea to include `Seq` as `Seq` adds lots of overhead (at least compared to int operations) so you risk that most of the time is spent in `Seq`, not in the code you like to test.

I wrote a small test program for `(+)`:

```
let clock = 
  let sw = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch ()
  sw.Start ()
  fun () ->
    sw.ElapsedMilliseconds

let dbreak () = System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break ()

let time a =
  let b = clock ()
  let r = a ()
  let n = clock ()
  let d = n - b
  d, r

module Unchecked =
  let run c () =
    let rec loop a i =
      if i < c then
        loop (a + 1) (i + 1)
      else
        a
    loop 0 0

module Checked =
  open Checked

  let run c () =
    let rec loop a i =
      if i < c then
        loop (a + 1) (i + 1)
      else
        a
    loop 0 0

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
  let count     = 1000000000
  let testCases =
    [|
      "Unchecked" , Unchecked.run
      "Checked"   , Checked.run
    |]

  for nm, a in testCases do
    printfn "Running %s ..." nm
    let ms, r = time (a count)
    printfn "... it took %d ms, result is %A" ms r

  0
```

The performance results are this:

```
Running Unchecked ...
... it took 561 ms, result is 1000000000
Running Checked ...
... it took 1103 ms, result is 1000000000
```

So it seems some overhead is added by using Checked. The cost of int add should be less than the loop overhead so the overhead of `Checked` is higher than `2x` maybe closer to `4x`.

Out of curiousity we can check the IL Code using tools like `ILSpy`:

Unchecked:

```
    IL_0000: nop
    IL_0001: ldarg.2
    IL_0002: ldarg.0
    IL_0003: bge.s IL_0014

    IL_0005: ldarg.0
    IL_0006: ldarg.1
    IL_0007: ldc.i4.1
    IL_0008: add
    IL_0009: ldarg.2
    IL_000a: ldc.i4.1
    IL_000b: add
    IL_000c: starg.s i
    IL_000e: starg.s a
    IL_0010: starg.s c
    IL_0012: br.s IL_0000
```

Checked:

```
    IL_0000: nop
    IL_0001: ldarg.2
    IL_0002: ldarg.0
    IL_0003: bge.s IL_0014

    IL_0005: ldarg.0
    IL_0006: ldarg.1
    IL_0007: ldc.i4.1
    IL_0008: add.ovf
    IL_0009: ldarg.2
    IL_000a: ldc.i4.1
    IL_000b: add.ovf
    IL_000c: starg.s i
    IL_000e: starg.s a
    IL_0010: starg.s c
    IL_0012: br.s IL_0000
```

The only difference is that Unchecked uses `add` and Checked uses `add.ovf`. `add.ovf` is add with overflow check.

We can dig even deeper by looking at the jitted `x86_64` code.

Unchecked:

```
; if i < c then
00007FF926A611B3  cmp         esi,ebx  
00007FF926A611B5  jge         00007FF926A611BD  
; i + 1
00007FF926A611B7  inc         esi  
; a + 1
00007FF926A611B9  inc         edi  
; loop (a + 1) (i + 1)
00007FF926A611BB  jmp         00007FF926A611B3
```

Checked:

```
; if i < c then
00007FF926A62613  cmp         esi,ebx  
00007FF926A62615  jge         00007FF926A62623  
; a + 1
00007FF926A62617  add         edi,1  
; Overflow?
00007FF926A6261A  jo          00007FF926A6262D  
; i + 1
00007FF926A6261C  add         esi,1  
; Overflow?
00007FF926A6261F  jo          00007FF926A6262D  
; loop (a + 1) (i + 1)
00007FF926A62621  jmp         00007FF926A62613
```

Now the reason for the `Checked` overhead is visible. After each operation the jitter inserts the conditional instruction `jo` which jumps to code that raises `OverflowException` if the overflow flag is set.

This [chart](http://ithare.com/infographics-operation-costs-in-cpu-clock-cycles/) shows us that the cost of an integer add is less than 1 clock cycle. The reason it's less than 1 clock cycle is that modern CPU can execute certain instructions in parallel.

The chart also shows us that branch that was correctly predicted by the CPU takes around 1-2 clock cycles.

So assuming a throughtput of at least 2 the cost of two integer additions in the Unchecked example should be 1 clock cycle.

In the Checked example we do `add, jo, add, jo`. Most likely CPU can't parallelize in this case and the cost of this should be around 4-6 clock cycles.

Another interesting difference is that the order of additions changed. With checked additions the order of the operations matter but with unchecked the jitter (and the CPU) has a greater flexibility moving the operations possibly improving performance.

So long story short; for cheap operations like `(+)` the overhead of `Checked` should be around `4x-6x` compared to `Unchecked`.

This assumes no overflow exception. The cost of a .NET exception is probably around `100,000x` times more expensive than an integer addition.